# Generic rule adding path to target

Tags: makefile

I want to build a Makefile that looks like below:

```
binfolder := bin    
objs := #...
bins := program1 secondprogram thethirdprogram
all: $(bins)

#does not work, how can I express this?
$(bins):%: $(binfolder)/% 

$(binfolder)/%: $(objs) _mainobj_%.o
   #g++  ...
```

Note the line that is not correct, but hopefully convey what I want accomplished. I want to be able to make targets without writing out the path myself, and without having to write an extra line per program. I guess the part of the problem is that i can not just use % alone as a target. How can I solve this?

Comment: So you want to be able to type `make program1`, and have it generate `bin/program1`?   You should post the output when you try it.

Comment: Well, it looks like it works (probably, the line `.PHONY: all $(bins)` is missing, but it's not really the problem). What's exactly the error message, and what `make` do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is with trailing whitespace:

```
binfolder := bin    #<- notice trailing whitespace.
                    # bindfolder is actually "bin    "...
```

So now your rule

```
$(bins):%: $(binfolder)/%
```

expands to:

```
program1 secondprogram thethirdprogram:%: bin    /%
```

which is likely causing your problem.   To check for things like this, you can add the following:

```
$(info binfolder is "$(binfolder)")
```